# Calculating sin(x) with Taylor series

Tags: c, math, formula

> **Task:** According to the Taylor Series of sin(x) calculate with using a double function named **mysin** pass it to a double variable. Take a x value from user and use the mysin function to calculate sin(x).
>
> [image: Sin()x Tyler Series Formula]

Problem is program gives me wrong value of sin(x). I have been trying to solve that issue about 4 hours but couldn't find it. Is it because of sin(x) function or have I missed something in my code?

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

double mysin(double x)
{
    double value = x;
    double sum = x;
    int neg_pos = 1;
    int fac = 1;
    
    int counter = 0;
    
    while(1)
    {
        neg_pos *= -1;
        fac += 2;
        
        value = value/(fac*(fac-1));
        value = value*x*x*neg_pos;

        sum += value;
        
        //printf("Hello");
        counter++;
        if (counter == 100) break;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    double number;
    scanf("%lf",&number);
    printf("%g",mysin(number));
    //printf("%g",number);
}
```

Comment: Problem is program gives me wrong value of sin(x). I have been trying to solve that issue about 4 hours but couldn't find it. Is it because of sin(x) function or i missed something in my code ?

Comment: I accidentally put the questin at the bottom of the code. Sorry :(

Comment: That factorial accumulation looks.... wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values? It shouldn't require many iterations before any mistakes in the calculation would become clear.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're multiplying by `neg_pos` each step, which toggles between +1 and -1. That means the terms change sign only half the time, whereas they should change sign each time.

The fix is to just multiply by -1 each time rather than `neg_pos`.

Here's a working, slightly-simplified form of your program that calculates sin for a range of numbers from 0 to 3, showing the stdlib calculation to compare.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double mysin(double x) {
    double value = x;
    double sum = x;
    int fac = 1;
    
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        fac += 2;
        value = -value*x*x/fac/(fac-1);
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    for (double x = 0.0; x < 3.0; x += 0.1) {
       printf("%g: %g %g\n", x, mysin(x), sin(x));
    }
}
```

You can also avoid the separate `fac` and `counter` variables, perhaps like this:

```
double mysin(double x) {
    double term=x, sum=x;
    for (int f = 0; f < 100; f++) {
        term = -term*x*x/(2*f+2)/(2*f+3);
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: When i convert all neg_pos to comment line and add "-", it works fine. But it doesnt make any sense. Why variable doesnt work and "-" works ? And how can "That means the terms change sign only half the time" be possible ?

Comment: `neg_pos` alternates between +1 and -1, so you're multiplying the previous term by +1 half the time, and -1 half the time. But the terms in the taylor series always have different signs from the term before them.

Comment: I think you're thinking of multiplying by `neg_pos` as setting the sign of the expression, but that's only true if thing you're multiplying it with is positive. You could try printing out the terms, and comparing them with the true value of `-1^n*x^n/n!`.

Answer (score -2):

From what I'm understanding you are not calculating the power correctly
Firtsly use this:

```
#include <math.h>
```

Then create a factorial function:

```
int factorial(int x){
   int result = 1;
   for(int i = 1; i < x; i++){
      result += result * i;
   }
   return result;
}
```

And finally:

```
while(1)
 {
    neg_pos *= -1;
    fac += 2;
    
    power = pow(x,fac);
    fac = factorial(fac);

    sum += power/fac;
    
    //printf("Hello");
    counter++;
    if (counter == 100) break;
}
```

Comment: The author of the question is trying to compute intermediate terms without recomputing the factorial each time. Computing x^fac and fac! separately result in HUGE numbers, which are then divided to give a very small number. They're so huge to cause overflows. Even 13! overflows a 32-bit int, and your code tries to calculate 200!. 200! has 375 digits, and is larger than even the largest double value.

Comment: You have a curious implementation of factorial. It's correct, but it looks wrong because the loop is apparently off-by-one, and there's a += in the computation. But it works because `r += r*i` is equivalent to `r = r * (i + 1)`. I wonder how you came to write it like this!

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize that. Calculating the factorial each time is very costly. It is much smarter storing its value continiously and calculate it from that!